# Do deployments affect/remove data export files?

Tags: deployment, data-export, backup

I am preparing to deploy a huge change set from Sandbox to Production. I have done a data export of Production which has generated 20+ .zip files = ~30gb. I am busy downloading these files, but don't want to have to wait until they are finished downloading before I deploy (I have a somewhat slow internet connection).

If I deploy my change sets to Production, is there ANY chance that it will influence/affect/remove the export .zip files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Data Export files are only removed when they expire (after 48 hours), regardless of any deployments that may occur after the end of a data export.